# Selenium Python: Wait for backgroundColor of Element to be 'rgb(...)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium and Python, how can we wait for a certain element with id `foo` to have a `backgroundColor` of `"rgb(1, 2, 3)"`?

So far, I think it should be something like this

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

expected_backgroundColor = EC.some_method((By.ID, "foo"))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(expected_backgroundColor)
```

but not sure which `EC` method to use.

Any advice will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `presence_of_element_located` or `visibility_of_element_located` methods for this. Let's see below example,

**Expected element `xPath`**:

```
//input[@id='rgb(1, 2, 3)']
```

**Code**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id='rgb(1, 2, 3)']')))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id='rgb(1, 2, 3)']')))
```

In Java, methods like `attributeToBe`, `attributeContains` and `attributeNotToBeEmpty` methods are available but not sure whether these methods are available in Python or not.

**Java example**:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xPath "));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(element, "id", "rgb(1, 2, 3)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would most likely use a custom wait function that runs a script on the client site to check the color.

Something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def has_expected_color(driver):
    return driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById(‘myid’).style.backgroundColor === ‘0xfff’")

WebDriverWait(driver).until(has_expected_color)
```